# How to pass a single struct instance along with an interator to map in Rust

Tags: loops, rust, vector, struct, rayon

I would like to iterate over a `Vec<T>`, but also pass a struct instance to my function.

The idea is that I can make a copy of the struct instance separately within each process and modify each copied struct instance based off of initial conditions that are stored in the `Vec<T>`.

Once again, I have a set of initial conditions that are stored in a Vec that I would like to use iteratively using `.iter()` to modify a set of struct instance copies.

My naive guess is that I would have to create an additional `Vec<StructType>` with the same length as `Vec<T>` and then create many copies inside of my struct instance within that `Vec<StructType>,` but I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way where each process could create a copy.

Here is an outline of what I am trying to do, though I am not sure what the best way to pass the `struct_instance` to my function is.

```
// --- PreProcessing ---
let struct_instance <StructType> = read_inputs(json);

// --- Iteration ---
let initial_conditions: Vec<i32> = (1..5).collect();
let test: Vec<i32> = initial_conditions
    .iter()
    .map(calculation_function)
    .collect();
```

I have left off the definition of the `read_inputs` and `calculation_function` from the code snippet because I feel that the full definition might detract from the main point of the question.

I later would like to parallelize this task with rayon, which is why I have chosen to use the `.iter()` approach.

Comment: You want... a bunch of copies of a struct, in a vec, that you modify iteratively, potentially in parallel? Why don't you just clone the original struct at each round of the iterator? What does `calculate_function` have to do with any of this? Is the struct supposed to be an extra parameter to it that you want partially applied? I appreciate your attempt to pare this down, but you've stripped out enough that I don't really understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: While the full definition of `caculation_function` is likely not needed, it's signature definitely is.

Comment: @cafce25, thank you for the edits, the question is definitely improved and more readable now.

Comment: @JaredSmith, thank you for your question, and yes your understanding is correct. 

I think that there are two possibilities for solving this problem.  Possibility one is that I create two vectors, one vector consisting of the struct instance repeated a bunch of times, and one vector which has the initial conditions that are needed to modify the struct instance. Possibility two is that I clone the original struct at each round of the iterator, but I am not sure how to do the second approach.

Comment: @cafce25, I agree the function signature is most definitely needed.  

`calculation_function(initial_condition, struct_instance)`

The initial condition is one index of the `Vec<T>` of initial condintions.

The struct_instance is one instance of the struct, whether it is an index of a `Vec<StructType>` or just the individual struct instance depends on which path we take to solving the problem. 

Answer by @Sam below shows the first way to solve the problem, I am not sure how to go about the second way.

Comment: Actually, playing with @Sam 's answer it looks like `iter::repeat` totally works for the second case, since `.iter` is just calling `next` on the iterator.  This totally works for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iter::repeat(SomeStruct { .. })` will give you an iterator that repeats the initial struct definition.

`initial_condition.iter().zip(iter::repeat(SomeStruct { .. })` will give you an iterator that gives you a tuple `(initial_condition, some_struct)` for each value contained in the initial_condition collection.

A full example would be something like the below. I changed the type of test from `i32` to `SomeStruct` since it seems like you're wanting to collect modified versions of the initial struct, but I might be misunderstanding your requirement.

```rust
use std::iter;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct SomeStruct {
    value: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let structs = iter::repeat(SomeStruct { value: 0 });

    let initial_conditions: Vec<i32> = (1..5).collect();
    let test: Vec<SomeStruct> = initial_conditions
        .iter()
        .zip(structs)
        .map(|(initial_condition, mut somestruct)| {
            somestruct.value = *initial_condition;
            somestruct
        })
        .collect();

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam this is exactly what I was looking for!